# jQuery toggle function for toggling specific div (and not all div with same class name.)

Tags: jquery, html

Each `<li></li>` has a toggle and a content class. 
Right now, when I click on toggle, every content item is shown. 
Using jQuery, how can I make sure only one content is displayed at a time?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var $content = $(".content").hide();
$(".toggle").on("click", function(e){
$(this).toggleClass("expanded");
$content.slideToggle();
});
});
</script>

  <li class="cell" id="bar1">
    <div id="update1"><?php echo $post?></div>
    <div class="toggle" id="toggle1"></div>
    <div id="check"><a href="#" class="check" id="check1">read</a></div> 
    <div class="upvote"><a href="#" class="like" id="1"><span class="thumbsup"></span>   
    </a></div>       
    <div class="upvote"><a href="#" class="like" id="upvote1">
    <div id="deletepost"><a href="#" id="1">delete</a></div>
    <div class="content" id="1"><img src="images/balloon.jpg"  
    </div>
  </li>
```

EDIT: .content is not the next sibling of .toggle. For clarity purposes, I removed a couple of divs that come between .toggle and .content.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$content.slideToggle()` to `$(this).next().slideToggle()` assuming that `.content` is always the next sibling of `.toggle`

EDIT: since it's not, what you can do is use the `postid`s.  I think it would be better to use the `data-postid` attribute instead of adding it to the `id` (or do both) so that you don't have to parse it from the ID.

```
$(".content[data-postid=" + $(this).data('postid') + "]").slideToggle();
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately .content isn't the next sibling of .toggle. That's the tricky part (I just edited my question). .content and .toggle are 5 div apart.

Comment: @CharlieHarris I need to see the actual HTML to help in that case

Comment: @CharlieHarris in this case you can use `.siblings`: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/yChvD/